# Why Is My Hibernate Entity (Message) Not Mapped?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I am using spring boot and hibernate with a configuration class. My entity isn't being mapped. See error below. After looking at a few other stackoverflow pages about this I still can't figure it out.

I believe the following is correct: HQL, @Entity, @Table

The error.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Message is not mapped
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
```

The entity.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name = "strunk.entities")
@Table(name = "Message")
public class Message {

code...
}
```

The DAO class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import strunk.entities.Message;

@Repository
public class MessageRepoImpl implements MessageRepo {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Override
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        Session sess = sf.openSession();
        List<Message> messages = null;

        try {
            messages = sess.createQuery("FROM Message").list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }
        
        return messages;
    }

    more code...
}
```

When I substitute the getMessages method body with the following it works

```
        Session sess = sf.openSession();
        List<Message> messages = sess.createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM Message" )
            .list();
        return messages;
```

The DB table name is 'Message'.

SpringBoot class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("strunk")
@EnableJpaRepositories("strunk")
@EntityScan("strunk")
public class InstantMessengeTranslatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InstantMessengeTranslatorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Hibernate config class

```
package strunk.config;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfig {
    
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClass;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
        datasource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        return datasource;
    }
    
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.xadmin.springboothibernate.model"});
        return factory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory factory)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManger = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManger.setSessionFactory(factory);
        return transactionManger;   
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should add entity package to scan in session factory bean initialization

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean. Are you suggesting I do something in the HibernateConfig class?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan-java.lang.String...- there should be a package to entity

Answer (score 0):

During spring bean initialization make your your entity class is being initialize. If its not added in componant scan then it will not considerd as bean class and Hibernate will through the error.

Comment: Can you tell me specifically what I should change. I am already using scanning the entities with "@EntityScan("strunk.entities")".

Comment: Itstead of using entity scan add package name in to componant scan. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the Hibernate config class, setPackagesToScan() was referencing the incorrect package. Thank you Alex.